# Hidden mesmo ID da Função gera erro

Tags: javascript, html

Como não ficou claro vou refazer a duvida.

segue o codigo que está funcionado como desejado.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/teste_andre.html" method="get" id="form1" onsubmit="return valida()">
        <input type='hidden' value='1' name='teste' id='teste'>
    </form>

    <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function valida(){alert('valida');}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se eu mudar o ID do campo tipo hidden de 'teste' para 'valida'
NÃO mostra o alert e não dá erro no console.

Só quero saber pq o hidden não pode ter o mesmo id do nome da função?

Comment: mostra o código do botão

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no console ?

Comment: Mostre o restante do código para vermos como você está implementando este formulário

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde amigo, isso é um erro do javascript mesmo, ele acaba se confundindo e impede você de usar ambos com os mesmos nomes.

Caso queira ver mais detalhes, pode conferir essa resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id